# Suppressing video controls under Google chrome doesn't work well

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

The programmatically start of a mp4/ogv video under chrome browser doesn't work perfect. At the startup time of the video the controls will be always shown for approx. 1 second before they disappear.

Does anyone knows about this problem. How can I suppress this behaviour?

Here the code fragment.

```
function setupMediaContainer(mediaUrl) {
mediaobj = document.createElement('video');
    mediaobj.src = mediaUrl;
mediaobj.setAttribute('autoplay',false);
mediaobj.setAttribute('controls',false);
mediaobj.addEventListener("ended", function() { getNextAdvertisingMedia()}); 
mediaobj.width=$(media_container).width();
mediaobj.height=$(media_container).height();    
$(media_container).append(mediaobj);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.  The controls appear to be going behind the video itself, as I can see just a few pixels of the controls on either side of the video.  Not sure how to solve this issue.

Edit: I should also add, I am not using jquery at all but I'm having the same problem.  I am using some DOM to add controls to my video as I can not control the other markup.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].setAttribute("controls", "controls");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line here:

```
mediaobj.setAttribute('controls',false);
```

This makes your video element look like this:

```
<video src="whatever.webm" width="320" height="240" autoplay controls="false"></video>
```

The browser doesn't care about the value of the `controls` attribute, only whether it's there. So just get rid of that line, and the controls should go away.